# How to change public folder to public_html in laravel 7?

Tags: php, laravel

There are a lot of solutions for Laravel 5.

For example:

edit `\App\Providers\AppServiceProvider` `register()` method.

```
public function register()
{
    // ...

    $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
        return base_path('public_html');
    });
}
```

or [this](https://medium.com/@pixelvars/laravel-change-public-html-to-public-html-the-right-way-496431aed94) or [this][2]

All solutions are different.

Is there a new official and standard solution especially for Laravel 7?

[2]: [https://developerhowto.com/2018/11/12/how-to-change-the-laravel-public-folder/#:~:text=.%2Fconfig%2Ffilesystems.&text=Modify%20the%20section%20'public'%20to,alias%20of%20your%20root%20folder](https://developerhowto.com/2018/11/12/how-to-change-the-laravel-public-folder/#:%7E:text=.%2Fconfig%2Ffilesystems.&text=Modify%20the%20section%20%27public%27%20to,alias%20of%20your%20root%20folder)).

Answer (score 0):

To change the public path of Laravel 7

Open the index.php file located at public/index.php

Then after the line: `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';`

Enter the following code below:

```
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
  return base_path().'/public_html';
});
```

You can change the `public_html` to any folder name you intend to use.

This works perfectly for me. Got it from https://www.skillsugar.com/how-to-change-the-public-directory-path-in-laravel-7